# Ignite SqlQuery for complex java objects

Tags: ignite

In my cache I have a complex java object as below -

```
    class Person{
    private Department d;
    ....
    }
class Department {
    private Department code;
    ....
    }
```

I am using below SQLQuery to read it -

```
     SqlQuery<Short, BinaryObject> query = new SqlQuery<>(Person.class, "d.code = ?");
String args="101"; // department code
    QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Short, BinaryObject>> resultSet = personCache.query(query.setArgs(args))
```

I am getting below error - 
Caused by: class `org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.IgniteSQLException: Failed to parse query: SELECT "PERSON_CACHE"."PERSONENTITY"._KEY, "TPERSON_CACHE"."PERSONENTITY"._VAL FROM "PERSON_CACHE"."PERSONENTITY" WHERE id.code = ?`

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by using predicate.

```
IgniteBiPredicate<Long, BinaryObject> predicate = new IgniteBiPredicate<Long, BinaryObject>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Long e1, BinaryObject e2) {
          Person p= e2.deserialize();
          short s = (short) args[0];
          return p.getId().getCode == s;
        }
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access nested fields, but only if they were configured with QuerySqlField annotation in advance:

```
class Person{
    private Department d;
    ...
}

class Department {
    @QuerySqlField
    private Department code;
    ....
}

SqlQuery<Short, BinaryObject> query = new SqlQuery<>(Person.class, "code = ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring is not supported by Ignite SQL and there are no solid plans to implement it.

This means you can't peek into fields that are rich objects, maps, lists, etc. You should introduce a departmentId numeric field here.

Theoretically you could also try putting @QuerySqlField annotation on Department's field `code`, and then access it as `CODE = ?`. Your mileage may vary. I for one would like to hear about the result of such experiment.